# It will be terminated immediately when installing MYSQL in AIX

Tags: mysql, aix

After running mysql_install_db in mysql/scripts, I ran mysqld_safe, and the following error appeared.

```
220329 00:08:10 mysqld_safe Logging to '/home/ts_dist/mysql57/data/daenerys.err'.
220329 00:08:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /home/ts_dist/mysql57/data
220329 00:08:11 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /home/ts_dist/mysql57/data/daenerys.pid ended
```

MySQL is tar.The gz file was moved to the corresponding directory and decompressed, and it was not installed with the rpm command.

Is it a problem that can occur during this process?

Comment: hi, were there any errors in the logs? perhaps use the init script to start mysql?

Comment: AIX is not in the list of supported OS for MySQL. Check this Q/A: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/228669